# httpd.exe - entry point not found : the procedure entry point free could not be located in library c:\xampp\apache\bin\libapriconv-1.dll

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, httpd.conf

I'm trying to run apache using Xampp , But I get that error:

```
he procedure entry point free could not be located in the dynamic link library  
c:\xampp\apache\bin\libapriconv-1.dll
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I installed Microsoft C++ 2008 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2015.

Also changed apache port:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 8080

ServerName localhost:8080
```

I installed Xampp on another disk , Didn't work , So I reinstalled it in the `C` disk.

I don't have an anti-virus installed.

I tried to run `xampp-control.exe` and `apache_start.bat` as administrator , But still the same.

Is there is something I'm missing to solve that issue?

Comment: I would take an educated guess that you have IIS runnning and it has allocated port 80 before you start XAMPP and specifically Apache in XAMPP as all web servers use port 80 by default. If you are not using IIS uninstall it

Comment: You may also need other MSVC Runtimes depending upon which version of Apache you are actually runnning. Its best to install all of them

Comment: @RiggsFolly , How to know if there is IIS running ? and what is MSVC Runtimes?

Comment: _You installed Microsoft C++ 2008 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2015._ but what about 2010/2012/2017 for both 32bit and 64bit

Comment: If port 80 is blocked/being used it is almost definitely IIS running. Google how to uninstall IIS

Comment: I opened `netstat` and port 80 is used by the system , But I changed `apache ` to port 8080`

Comment: IIS always reports port 80 as being used by Process 4 (the system)

Comment: I installed 2005 , 2008 , 2010 , 2012 , 2015 and 2017 but I had an error while installing 2017

Comment: But I still have the same problem , MYSQL works fine but apache doesn't